# Django: Store List of Users in model?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I would like to be able to store a list of Users (The built-in Django auth module users) as a field in my model, kind of like this:

```
class EducationalClass(models.Model):
    students = UserListField()
```

Obviously there is no UserListField, so my question is, how would I store a list of users in my model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a ManyToMany field related to your User object?

```
class EducationalClass(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Then for any given `EducationalClass` you could access `.students.all()`, `.students.filter(...)` and all of the other methods available to querysets.

Comment: A FK would be advisable if each EducationalClass could only relate to one User - the MTM relation assumes each class can have many students and each student can belong to many classes. (This was a reply to a now-deleted comment; I'll leave it here for clarification in case anyone else reads this and thinks about using a ForeignKey instead)

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even know about the ManyToMany field. Clearly there's quite a bit I need to learn about Django...

Comment: No worries! Check out the docs here on available field types: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#field-types